# Does the "Number Doughnut" make sense?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

It's well known that is we add a point at infinity to the complex plane then we get the Riemann Sphere, or extended complex plane.

What if we distinguish between real infinity and imaginary infinity?

We identify $a+\mathrm i \infty$ with $a-\mathrm i \infty$ for each $a \in \mathbb R$, and separately we identify $\infty + \mathrm i b$ with $-\infty + \mathrm i b$ for each $b \in \mathbb R$? This would give the product of two projectively extended real lines and, in theory, something homeomorphic to the torus, i.e. a "number doughnut".

Is this object possible, is it well know, are there any references?

Comment: How then would you define $\lim_{r\to\infty}(r+ir)$? Would you allow $\infty+i\infty$?

Comment: @MPW I don't know, but I'd imagine it'd be like how the vertices of the flat torus model all get identified as the same point. If that's not possible then would it be a torus minus a point?

Comment: @FlybyNight the tags I suggested are at least tangentially relevant, and I suspect that using more common tags will get this question more visibility

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Fair point regarding visibility.

Comment: To be precise, it's not the product of two extended real lines, but two projectively extended real lines, since the latter identifies $-\infty$ with $+\infty$, and the former does not.

Comment: @heropup Thanks, that's what I meant to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely consider the product of two projectively extended real number lines as a topological space, and it would be a torus. However, it's not a meaningfully "complex" object.

Specifically, we are considering the space $X= (\Bbb{R} \cup \{\infty\})^2$. There is an obvious embedding $\iota: \Bbb{R}^2 \to X$. If we want to consider $X$ as a complex manifold in any reasonable sense, that presumably means identifying $\Bbb{R}^2$ with $\Bbb{C}$ and then putting a complex structure on $X$ which makes $\iota$ holomorphic. Since the image of $\iota$ is contractible, it lifts to the universal cover of $X$, which — by the [uniformization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem) — we can take to be $\Bbb{C}$ with its standard complex structure. But then this gives a bounded holomorphic map from $\Bbb{C}$ to itself, which is impossible by Liouville's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

You can define this if you want.  But (so far) there are no useful applications of it.  Unlike the Riemann sphere, which has some useful applications.

Comment: I don't entirely agree with this answer (specifically, the 'you can define this if you want' piece of it). The 'Riemann sphere' is constructed through a specific compactification process, and it's not at all clear to me that the compactification OP is talking about is well-defined in the same sense.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: What do you mean? That there is no universal property?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are NO $\infty$ and $-\infty$ in the complex numbers.  There are, rather, and infinite number of different "infinities", on as you leave the origin of the complex plane along any straight line.

In the **real** numbers, we can either add $\infty$ and $-\infty$ to have an "extended" real number system that is topologically equivalent to a closed line segment.  Or we can add a single $\infty$ that makes the line topologically equivalent to a circle.

In the complex numbers,  we can add an infinite number of "infinities" as above so that the complex plane is topologically equivalent to a disk or we can add a single "infinity" so that it is topologically equivalent to a sphere.